# Java date format convert yy to yyyy issue

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Java Date format issue, when I try to convert date 04-Apr-17 using below code:

```
       DateFormat informat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
       DateFormat outformat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
       System.out.println(outformat.format(informat.parse("04-Apr-17")));
```

I got 04-Apr-0017 instead of 04-Apr-2017.

I had tried many ways but don't got any good solution.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: For me it works fine

Comment: I cannot reproduce your observed behaviour either. What is your computer’s (or rather, JVM’s) default locale? For `04-Apr-7` I get `04-Apr-0007` alright, but 17 becomes 2017.

Comment: Since Giovanni Montenegro hasn’t yet got enough reputation for commenting, [here is the link to his demonstration that the code works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHiZh.png).

Comment: In any case what you are doing is dangerous unless you are very sure about how distant dates into the past or the future you are going to convert. Say that you convert `05-Apr-37` to `05-Apr-1937`, test and make sure everything is working fine. When you run the same program next week, it will convert to `05-Apr-2037` instead, a huge error.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the current date/time on that PC and also the locale of the PC: or if this also happens when you supply a dedicated locale: e..g US to the SimpleDateFormat()

Comment: I tried with all available locales in my Java 8 JVM. Those that let me parse `04-Apr-17`, all parse into 2017. Some (where the month of April has a different name, for example) throw an exception. In no case do I get year 17 AD (`0017`).

Comment: be ready for Y3K crisis :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason for this issue, I was using this date conversion in JSF environment & was checking for the pattern of date entered by user from web page.
And when user is passing "dd-MMM-yy" pattern, I have below code to parse the date for some supported date patterns list.

```
    Date date = null;
    boolean isDateValid = false;
    for (String pattern : patterns) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        try {
            date = df.parse(value);

            String newDateString = df.format(date);
            System.out.println(newDateString);

            isDateValid = true;
            break;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Date : " + date);
```

So, when user provides the date in "dd-MMM-yy" pattern, but "dd-MMM-yy" pattern is also parsed by "dd-MMM-yyyy" pattern in below code:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    date = df.parse(value);
```

And that's the reason, I was getting 04-Apr-0017 instead of 04-Apr-2017.